# How to pass parameter message as text in openpgp JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, openpgp.js

What I'm trying to do:

- get some Azure storage blobs from container DIDE and encrypt them with RSA 2048 and upload them in other container called *encrypted-dide*
  These blobs are downloaded through a stream(here Microsoft did a good job https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-nodejs#upload-blobs-to-a-container) and recomposed by func. *streamToString(readableStream)*
  (I'm not using openpgp JS streams as I don't know if Microsoft streams are the same with NodeJs ones)
- My code works as expected with unecrypted text and upload blobs in the supposedly encryped container *encrypted-dide*
- I have followed the official documentation of openpgp js and some Internet resources.
- The error I am getting is ***Error: Parameter [message] needs to be of type Message in openpgp JS***

the publicKey is harcoded in the file keys.js and and is exported like this:

```
const publicKey = `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=Wg0i
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`
```

- The code is:

```
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');
// const { v1: uuidv1 } = require('uuid');
// const stream = require('stream').promises
const openpgp = require('openpgp');
// import * as openpgp from 'openpgp'
const { publicKey } = require('./keys')





async function main() {

   const AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING = process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING;
   const blobServiceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
   const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("uploadebs");
   const containerEncryptedFiles = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient("encrypted-dide");
   await containerEncryptedFiles.createIfNotExists("encrypted-dide") 
   
  // console.log(await openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKey })) <- THIS WORKS!
   for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {

       if (blob.name.match('^DIDE*')) {
           const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
           const encryptedblockBlobClient = containerEncryptedFiles.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name)
           blockBlobClient.download(0)
           .then(downloadBlockBlobResponse => streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody))
           .then(blobAsString => openpgp.encrypt({
                   message:  openpgp.createMessage({ text: blobAsString }), // input as Message object
                   publicKeys: openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKey }), 
                   
               }))
            // BELOW LINE, SENDS TEXT IN BLOBS, ENCRYPTED OR NOT THROUGH FUNC UPLOAD
           .then(encrypted => {encryptedblockBlobClient.upload(encrypted, encrypted.length)})
       }
   }

}

async function streamToString(readableStream) {

 
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       const chunks = [];
       readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
           chunks.push(data.toString());
       });

       readableStream.on("end", () => {
           resolve(chunks.join(""));
       });
       readableStream.on("error", reject);
   });
}

main().then(() => console.log('Done')).catch((ex) => console.log(ex.message));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`openpgp.createMessage` returns a Promise. So you need to do `.then` or add `await` before it.

Same with `penpgp.readKey`. It is also a promise.

For example from the [Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openpgp):

```
const publicKey = await openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKeyArmored });

const encrypted = await openpgp.encrypt({
    message: await openpgp.createMessage({ text: 'Hello, World!' }), // input as Message object
    publicKeys: publicKey, // for encryption
    privateKeys: privateKey // for signing (optional)
});
```

**EDIT2:**
Without using await.

```
.then(blobAsString => {
    return Promise.all([openpgp.createMessage({ text: blobAsString }), openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKey })])
    .then(([message, publicKeys ])=>{
        return openpgp.encrypt({
            message,
            publicKeys,
        });
    });    
})
```

Comment: I am already in a then chain in order to control the flow.
Please let me know how you would integrate your response as I need also to wait for 'blobAsString' result

Comment: edited. you can use `then` chains in there as well.

Comment: I have tried like this before and gives a syntax error :/, apparently await it cannot be used in a then block

Comment: @arita-chakraborty
I have tried like this
            .then(blobAsString => {                
                Promise.all([openpgp.createMessage({ text: blobAsString }), openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKey })])
            })
            .then(v => console.log(v))
but gives me 3??? times undefined

Comment: seems to be very close to what I just added as well. check this new edit out @AB I think in ur solution u were not returning the encrypt function

Comment: @arita-chakraborty
Finally some other error code :). Thanks for your code, at least is a starting point 
<<<Error: Error encrypting message: No keys, passwords, or session key provided.>>

Answer (score 0):

Used like this:

```
            .then(blobAsString => {
                return Promise.all([openpgp.createMessage({ text: blobAsString }), openpgp.readKey({ armoredKey: publicKey })])
                .then(([message, publicKeys ])=>{
                    return openpgp.encrypt({
                        message,
                        publicKeys,
                    })                   
                })
                .then(encrypted => {encryptedblockBlobClient.upload(encrypted, encrypted.length)});;    
            })
```

Comment: can u accept the other answer given that you just used the code in ur solution. and add this code in the question itself.